# WebService call over asmx file not working. When Execute with console it work

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, https, asmx

I have project lets call it Service.dll

When i do this calling from an exe everything works fine. The Service is calling an `https://webservice` and gives me the results.

```
 Service service = new Service();
 var result = service.Get("276055580127912", "Item2015");
```

Now i try to do the same when calling the service from an asmx webservice.

So i created an asmx file with this code:

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="Service.asmx.cs" Class="Service" %>
```

When i host this asmx locally on my machine(BY VS) and try call the method Get I always get an Timeout message. It should only take about 1 sec.

Anyone an Idea why this is not working?

Thanks Markus

Answer (score 0):

well if you added the web service through "add web reference". You shouldn't had the problem. Maybe your service doesn't work fine,

Well, there is always an option, which is closing the projects and closing the service(you can find it on notification area bottom right) and open all the project, then start the service and start your app again.

If your code is fine, this have to do the trick.